# How to check BindingContext for the presence of something in it?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

1. create new stack and pass data

```
// This code is the main page of the application.
await Navigation.PushAsync(new TodoItemPage
{
BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as Models.TodoItem,
});
```

2. data is transferred in TodoItemPage

```
public TodoItemPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
Title = "Name"; // here need show NAME - I can't display my name here
var nameEntry = new Entry();
nameEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Name");
Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(20),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                Children =
                {
                    new Label { Text = "Name" },
                    nameEntry, // here NAME is shown
                }
            };
```

How to get the value of a property from a BindingContext to a variable on the TodoItemPage page?

VS, C#, Xamarin-Forms

I tried it

```
var data = (Models.TodoItem)BindingContext;
data.ID;
data.Name;
```

...

Comment: Cast BindingContext to your object class.

Answer (score 0):

Cast BindingContext from object class.

Example:

```
 public class TodoItem
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

then use

```
var data =  BindingContext as TodoItem;
var val1 = data.Prop1;
var val2 = data.Prop2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to acces the BindingContext in the constructor of TodoItemPage? It shouldnt be available their. The setter of BindingContext is called after the constructor code is done.
If you want to access it you can add an event in the constructor to this.BindingContextChanged 
and access the value their

[Update]
you cant acces BindingContext in the Constructor because the setting of  `BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as Models.TodoItem`is done after all your code in `public TodoItemPage()
{...}` has been exectuted. 
You can do the following to update those values according to the bindingcontext

```
Entry m_nameentry; //to access it later outside of the constructor
public TodoItemPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContextChanged += TodoItemPage_BindingContextChanged; //put the code that should use the BindingContext Value inside
    //Title = "Name"; // here need show NAME - I can't display my name here
    //var nameEntry = new Entry();
    m_nameentry = new Entry();
    nameEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Name");
    Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(20),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Children =
            {
                new Label { Text = "Name" },
                //nameEntry, // here NAME is shown
                m_nameentry
            }
        };
}

private void TodoItemPage_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Title = (BindingContext as Models.TodoItem).Name;
    m_nameentry.Text = (BindingContext as Models.TodoItem).Name;
}
```

This will update your Entry and the Title everytime the BindingContext Changes.
If Models.TodoItem implements the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface and you also want updates if the Value of Name changes after the Binding has been done you have to register on the PropertyChangedEvent of Models.TodoItem and do everything there.

Comment: corrected the question. I’m trying to access the BindingContext in the constructor of TodoItemPage from TodoItemPage.

Answer (score 0):

I use two pages, one is Page20, another is Page21. There is ListView in Page20, ListView selectedItem is the BindingContext for Page21. Here is the code sample:

Page20:

```
  <ListView ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelectedAsync" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page20 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<TodoItem1> items { get; set; }
    public Page20 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        items = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem1>()
        {
            new TodoItem1(){Id=1,Name="aaa"},
            new TodoItem1(){Id=2,Name="bbb"},
            new TodoItem1(){Id=3,Name="ccc"},
            new TodoItem1(){Id=4,Name="ddd"},
            new TodoItem1(){Id=5,Name="eee"},
            new TodoItem1(){Id=6,Name="fff"},
            new TodoItem1(){Id=7,Name="ggg"},
            new TodoItem1(){Id=8,Name="hhh"}

        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }



    private async void ListView_ItemSelectedAsync(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page21 {BindingContext=e.SelectedItem as TodoItem1 });
    }
}

public class TodoItem1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Page21

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page21 : ContentPage
{
    public Page21 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        Title = "Name"; // here need show NAME - I can't display my name here
        var nameEntry = new Entry();
        nameEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Name");
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(20),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Children =
            {
                new Label { Text = "Name" },
                nameEntry, // here NAME is shown
            }
        };
    }

    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = this.BindingContext as TodoItem1;
        Console.WriteLine(data.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Name);
    }
}
```